# Funding for new faculty

Tags: peer-review, funding, nih, professorship

looking for advice on what factors do granting agencies such as NIH takes into account while funding new researchers.
I am set to start as a new faculty soon. My Post-doc was short because of the faculty position offer. I could not generate preliminary data for the research area that I am interested in for a million reasons nevermind. Please, can anyone advise me on how to navigate the grants? I am reading books on the subjects but they assume the ideal PI, the Ideal Postdoc with the ideal supervisor, and unfortunately, my situation is tight with limited publications and high aspirations.  Any advice will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Reaching out to senior faculty in your dept. will be of great help. Many schools have a proposal development office who conducts seminars + talks for new faculty and new hires.

Comment: @Buffy thanks! noted!

Answer (score 4):

Reaching out to senior faculty in your dept. will be of great help. Many schools have a proposal (or grant) development office that conducts seminars + talks for new faculty and new hires.